# Where should I create an after create hook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following models:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :architecture
end

class Architecture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
end
```

And after a new page is saved I need to capture it's architecture (number of paragraphs por example). I would like to know what is the proper way to do that. I'm not sure if I should leave that responsible for the Page model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :architecture

  after_create :scrape_architecture

  private

  def scrape_architecture
    data = call_something_to_capture_architecture(url)
    create_architecture(data)
  end
end

class Architecture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page
end
```

or if it should be the responsibility of the Architecture model:

```
class Page < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :architecture

  after_create :create_architecture
end

class Architecture < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :page

  before_create :scrape_page

  private

  def scrape_page
    data = call_something_to_capture_architecture(page.url)
    create(data)
  end
end
```

Which is actually incorrectly because `before_create` runs after the validation – causing MySQL errors duo to non null constraints

Thank you.

Comment: I would question if you want to use a model callback instead of just doing it in your controller at the exact point you want it to happen. Callbacks are like carpet bombing.

Comment: Definitely... this has nothing to do with the controller. As soon as a page is created I want to scrape its architecture. This process has nothing to do with the view. The page shouldn’t exist with the architecture. Why model callbacks are carpet bombing? Could you elaborate?

Comment: Because it's really hard to control where and when the callbacks will be fired.

Comment: If you callback does something complex like using a web scraper its going to be a royal PITA to test your model as you can't save it without triggering all that. It also won't let you move the "callback logic" into a background task so that you can speed up the response.

Comment: Hm interesting. I’m using a library built internally to scrape the architecture, yes! I would love to see an example of how you would do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a [job](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html) or [service object](https://www.toptal.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-service-objects-tutorial) that handles scraping.

```
class PageScrapingJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(page)
    data = call_something_to_capture_architecture(page.url)
    architecture = page.create_actitecture(data)
    # ...
  end
end
```

You would then call the service/job in your controller after saving the page:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  def create 
    @page = Page.new(page_params)
    if @page.save
      PageScrapingJob.perform_now(@page)
      redirect_to @page
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

This gives you a perfect control of exactly when this is fired and avoids placing even more responsibilities onto your models. Even though your models may contain little code they have a huge amount of responsibilities such as validations, I18n, form binding, dirty tracking etc that are provided by ActiveModel and ActiveRecord. The list really goes on and on.

This instead creates a discrete object that does only one job (and hopefully does it well) and that can be tested in isolation from the controller.

Answer (score 0):

For such things you could use a service pattern

```
class PageScrapper
  Result = Struct.new(:success?, :data)

  def initialize(url)
    @url = url
  end

  def call
     result = process(@url)
     ...
     if result.success? # pseudo methods
       Result.new(true, result)
     else
       Result.new(false, nil)
     end
  end
end


class Fetcher
  ...
  def call
    scrapper = PageScrapper.new(url)
    result = scrapper.call

    if scrapper.success?
      page = Page.build(parsed_result_if_needed(result)
      page.architecture.build(what_you_need)
      page.save # here you need to add error handling if save fails
    else
     # error handling
    end
  end
```

There are a lot of resources about why callbacks are bad.
[Here is one from  Marcin Grzywaczewski](https://medium.com/planet-arkency/the-biggest-rails-code-smell-you-should-avoid-to-keep-your-app-healthy-a61fd75ab2d3) but you can also google it "why callbacks are bad ruby on rails".

By using service you are liberating models from having too much business logic and they do not need to know about other parts of your system.